# How to change which template is extended based on user authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I am using Laravel 6.20.11, and I have published the Laravel blade error templates. What I need to have happen is that if the user is authenticated, the error message extends the internal-only layout, and if not, it extends the public layout like so:

```
@auth
    @extends ('int-layouts.partials.wrapper')
    @section ('error')
        <div class="be-content">
            <div class="main-content container-fluid">
                <div class="container py-5">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <div class="text-block">
                                 <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
                                  <p class="text-muted text-uppercase mb-4">Sorry, we couldn't find the page you were looking for.
                                  Please contact the administrator<br/>
                                  Or go back to the <a class="navbar-brand py-1" href="/controlpanel/">Dashboard</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endsection
@endauth
@guest
    @extends ('ext-layouts.master')
    @section('error')
        <div class="container py-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="text-block">
                         <h1>404</h1>
                          <p class="text-muted text-uppercase mb-4">Sorry,You are trying to reach the page that does not exist.<br>
                           Please contact the administrator <br/> Or go back to the <a class="navbar-brand py-1" href="/">Home Page</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endsection
@endguest
```

The problem I am having is that when I test the 404 error using `abort(404)` or by trying to access a route that doesn't exist, the error message displays twice and the page inherits the int-layouts.partials.wrapper even when the user isn't authenticated.

Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong in my blade file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a conditional in one `@extends` directive:

```
@extends (auth()->check() ? 'int-layouts.partials.wrapper' : 'ext-layouts.master')
```

Then you can use a conditional after this inside your section.

```
@section('error')
    @auth
    @else
    @endif
@endsection
```

The `@extends` directive is not actually returning output directly into the compiled result like most directives do. The compiled PHP for this is held in an array to be added later.

Everything inside the `( )` of the directive is being used as a literal to call `make` on the View Factory:

```
"<?php echo \$__env->make({$expression}, \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), ['__data', '__path']))->render(); ?>"
```

If you found the compiled view for this Blade template you would see this:

```
<?php echo \$__env->make(auth()->check ? 'int-layouts.partials.wrapper' : 'ext-layouts.master', \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), ['__data', '__path']))->render(); ?>
```

The first argument to `make` ends up being your view name when this compiled view is executed.

Comment: Great! I didn't know you could add parameters to the @extends directive. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Controller function:
$layouts = Auth::user->admin ? 'view.admin' : 'view.student'; //
view.admin or view.student is the blade file which you want to render
dynamically.

```
return view('welcome',compact('layouts'));
```

Write in Blade File:

```
@extends($layouts)
@section('...')
...
@endsection
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it